# Converting string list to a list of type abstract class

Tags: c#, class, type-conversion, abstract-class

I created an abstract class with an overloaded constructor. I had to create a list of type `CMember`. I am unable to convert the string list to the list of type `CMember`.

I am trying to create a list in a seperate class but I cannot seem to figure it out. I am retrieving the data from a text file into the list of strings and I want to add it to the list "member"

```
//below is the abstract class I created
abstract class CMember
{
    public CMember(string name_)
    {
        name_ = Name; //I am also unsure whether I switched these the wrong way around
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}


List<string> Data = new List<string>();
List<CMember> member = new List<CMember>();
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    Data.Add(reader.ReadLine());
    
}
foreach (var item in Data)
{

    member.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: You need to know the actual concrete type for this to have any chance of working. You cannot instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: "I am also unsure whether I switched these the wrong way" Yes, you did :D
You don't want to assign a value to the parameter variable but to the property. On the left side is the assignment target and on the right side is the value that you assign. See: [Assignment operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator)

Comment: Or, perhaps more likely, you should use a serialization library that supports polymorphism, like `system.text.json`, so that you can take your data objects, write them to a file, and read it back. That lets the library handle the creation of the objects.

Comment: @JonasH I am guessing he has a simple file with names.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add more detail to your question. What does the data in the file look like? Why is your class abstract? Is there a concrete implementation of this class? As JonasH has pointed out, abstract classes cannot be instantiated because, well, they are abstract.

Comment: you must use `member.Add(new CMember(item));` instead of `member.Add(item);`. if you want to convert string to CMember without calling constructor you must use [explicit operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) but i dont recommend that at this situation.

Comment: `abstract` classes should not have `public` constructors, as only derived classes should initialize them.  There is no reason for `CMember` to be abstract here, as there is no functionality defined that the derived classes would handle.

Answer (score 3):

Well, `List<CMember> member` is a list of `CMember` so we have to create `CMember` instances and put them into `member` list:

```
foreach (var item in Data)
{
    // We must create CMember's from string
    // Doesn't compile, please see below
    member.Add(new CMember(item));
}
```

However, a problem arises. You *can't create an instance* of an `abstract class` (it doesn't matter if it has a constructor or not):

```
// Doesn't compile
new CMember("some name");
```

So you should either turn `CMember` to be a non-abstract one:

```
// If CMember is not abstract its instance can be created
class CMember { ... }

...

List<string> Data = new List<string>();

...

List<CMember> member = new List<CMember>(); 

foreach (var item in Data)
{
    // Here we can call CMember constructor
    member.Add(new CMember(item));
}
```

Or if you want to keep `CMember` being `abstract` you have to create an instance of some *concrete* class:

```
// Note, that MyCMember is not abstract
class MyCMember : CMember() {
  public MyCMember(string _name) : base(_name) {}
}

...

List<string> Data = new List<string>();

...

List<CMember> member = new List<CMember>(); 

foreach (var item in Data)
{
    // Note that we can create an instance of concrete class only: MyCMember
    member.Add(new MyCMember(item));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an implicit conversion between `string` and `CMember` if the class is *not* abstract.

```
public class CMember
{
    public CMember(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public static implicit operator CMember(string name) => new CMember(name);
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader reader = ...;
        List<CMember> list = new List<CMember>();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)                 
        {
            string input = reader.ReadLine();
            list.Add(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you do not need two lists for filling `List<CMember>`. Each line you read from the stream can be added to the list as `CMember` directly, utilizing the implicit conversion defined in `CMember`.